# How to clean spaces in a NSString

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, spaces

I would like to reduce the number of spaces between two words in a NSString (Objective-C/iPhone dev) to only one. Do you know some method that could do that ?

Exemple :

Before cleaning : "Hi,       my   name       is                Tom."
After cleaning : "Hi, my name is Tom."

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `[mystring componentsSeparatedByString:@" "]` to get a `NSArray` of all substrings separated by a single space.  Then, recombine the non-empty strings in the array to get the final string.

Comment: Thanks, I think this the simplier way to get what I want ;)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at http://regexkit.sourceforge.net/, it has `NSString` extensions with which you could do regex-based string replace.

Answer (score 1):

using [RegexKit](http://regexkit.sourceforge.net/Documentation/index.html), adding to RSC's answer

```
NSString *subjectString     = @"Hi,       my   name       is                Tom.";
NSString *regexString       = @"(\\s+)";
NSString *replacementString = @" ";

NSString *newString = [subjectString stringByMatching:regexString replace:RKReplaceAll withString:replacementString];
```